# dsx model builder using regression error

Tags: data-science-experience

I'm trying to train a very simple model in IBM DSX - Data Science Experience, using Regression, where I'm providing a time series with value and date, but I keep on getting a training error. The data comes from DSX data asset (created from a CSV file, containing #of events per date (int) and the respective dates, that I have successfully managed to load and preview, using comma as separator, with the 1st line providing the column names). For Column value to predict (Label Col), I selected the name of the column containing the #of events per date. For the Feature columns, I provided the name of the column containing the dates (which DSX correctly understood as dates). For Validation Split, I kept the defaults (Train: 60, Test: 20, Holdout: 20). Below is the error message that I'm getting. Please advise.

Training Error
requirement failed: Invalid number of input columns java.io.PrintWriter@28a4f83b

Comment: Are you still encountering this issue? If so, can you share your input file, or some sample values from your input file?